# How to handle key press events with the QPlainTextEdit

Tags: events, qt, key

I've been developing with QT for around a week now and am pleased to say that I'm picking it up really fast. I'm an intermediate C++ programmer but picking up some parts of QT is proving to be challenging. I need to process key press events from the QPlainTextEdit when the user presses enter and I presume that the solution will involve sub classing the widget. Can any of you smart guys give me a potential implementable solution?

Answer (score 7):

To really understand Qt and event handling there are two key areas of the documentation you should read. The first is the overview on [The Event System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/eventsandfilters.html) and the second is a very important bit which is a cleverly hidden link on that page for [QCoreApplication::notify](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#notify). They should really move that to the main page of the Event System documentation as it really makes things quite clear (to me at least).

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to handle some messages sent to the control - like the key-presses - there is no need to subclass it. You can alternatively use the event filtering mechanism. Here is a simple example:

1. Provide virtual eventFilter method in one of your QObject-based classes (e.g. the window form class).

   ```
   bool MyWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
   {
       if(watched == ui->myTargetControl)
       {
           if(event->type() == QKeyEvent::KeyPress)
           {
               QKeyEvent * ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
               if(ke->key() == Qt::Key_Return || ke->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
               {
                   // [...]
                   return true; // do not process this event further
               }
           }
           return false; // process this event further
       }
       else
       {
           // pass the event on to the parent class
           return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Install your class as the event filter for the target control. Form constructor is usually a good place for this code. In the following snippet `this` refers to the instance of class in which you implemented the `eventFilter` method.

   ```
   ui->myTargetControl->installEventFilter(this);
   ```

Comment: Nice solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

i would try subclassing `QPlainTextEdit` and reimplementing `QWidget::keyPressEvent`:

```
void YourTextEdit::keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
{
  if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Return )
  {
    // optional: if the QPlainTextEdit should do its normal action 
    // even when the return button is pressed, uncomment the following line
    // QPlainTextEdit::keyPressEvent( event )

    /* do your stuff here */
    event->accept();
  }
  else
    QPlainTextEdit::keyPressEvent( event )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try :

```
if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return || event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter){
//do something
}
```

in your **keyPressEvent()** function.