# QTextEdit - How to "cancel" entered key codes in onKeyPress()

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to "`cancel`" key codes in `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit`. When I say cancel, what I mean is, I want to turn the "entered" character into "nothing" depending on the key entered. Example: if the user hits "a" or "b" on the keyboard, I would not want to have "a" or "b" displayed / entered into the text, instead, the input would be ignored and turned into nothing / won't be processed.

With C++ Builder, you have a `KeyDown_Event` and a "Key" parameter. Once you detect the entered key code, if you don't like it, you can set the "Key" parameter to 0, so you set "Key = 0" and the key stroke would not be displayed. How do I achieve the same thing in Qt?

Let me explain with code:

```
if (e->key() == 67)
    // do not send "c" to the QTextEdit (In C++ Bullder, you would do Key = 0)

if (e->key() == 65)
    // do not send "a" to the QTextEdit (In C++ Bullder, you would do Key = 0)
```

How do I do this in Qt?

I tired doing e->setAccepted(false) and e->Ignore() but it made no difference. I think by the time e->ignore() is executed, the "char" is already inserted into the text box. With C++ Builder, you can intercept this with the KeyDown event and cancel it. I can't seem to find a way with Qt.

Thx

Comment: Maybe you need: [The old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476745/how-to-handle-key-press-events-with-the-qplaintextedit) ?

Comment: Did you try with `event->ignore();` ?

Comment: Yes I did try (I modified my post to state this) but it doesn't make a difference because by the time event->ignore() is run, the char is already displayed in the box. With C++ Builder, you can literally intercept this by saying Key = 0 where "Key" is a reference to type and that way the event system knows not to display the char.

Comment: Since you opted for Qt you may not be interested in a quality UI anyway. Still, had you considered, that text can be entered without pressing keys (e.g. pasting contents from the clipboard)?

Comment: @IInspectable : `Since you opted for Qt you may not be interested in a quality UI anyway` What? what's wrong with Qt?

Comment: @Thomas: Qt's inherent inability to produce a **reliable** interface. This mostly manifests itself, when trying to implement proper keyboard support, but is not limited to it. Input focus is usually unpredictable after even short input sequences. It's obsession to discard native input timestamps, and - wrongfully - forward-dating events with its own invented timestamps. Not an issue for everyone, but when it is for you, this is unfixable, and you're left with a sub-standard quality UI. I could go on and on and on, but this is a comment on SO, and size is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `void QObject::installEventFilter ( QObject * filterObj )` example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    textEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (watched == textEdit && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *e = static_cast < QKeyEvent * >(event);
        if (e->key() == Qt::Key_A) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As **IInspectable** noticed, this won't help you with filtering `Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V` method. If you need these either, you'll need to connect to `QTextEdit::textChanged` signal and updated the text manually. Something like this:

```
static QString oldString;
QString s = textEdit->toPlainText();
if (s == oldString)
   return;
int pos = textEdit->textCursor().position();
s.remove('a', Qt::CaseInsensitive);
oldString = s;
textEdit.setPlainText(s);
QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();
cursor.setPosition(pos);
textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: Can't blame you for answering the question that was asked. Still, this is going to produce an inconsistent UI. You'll know, when someone comes around to paste contents from the clipboard, and simply sidesteps your carefully crafted logic.

Comment: Of cource, if you need to remove all 'a' simbols from any source, you need to connect to a `textChanged` signal and edit the text properly, but, as you noticed... just answering hte question ^_^.

Comment: Ok thx, I will try that and see if it works. I have paid attention to the warnings, thank you for that.

Comment: Your update is almost correct: You'll have to guard against the infinite recursion, as `setPlainText()` causes another `textChanged` signal to be emitted.

Comment: Your last edit needlessly limits the implementation to a single widget. Why not use an automatic `QString` and compare that to the result of the `s.remove()`-call instead? If they are the same, move on. Otherwise replace the contents.

Comment: What's an 'automatic QString'? Comparing to self is a nice idea, though, since I use `textEdit` name, using static variable here is not a limitation.

Comment: Automatic variables are a concept of C++. Variables that are neither class members nor have static storage duration. They are called *automatic* because their lifetime is controlled automatically (i.e. when they go out of scope).