# C++ Visual Studio 2012 Forms

Tags: c++, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I have a problem with Forms in Visual Studio.

I created my UI, that takes data from inputs and after clicking the button saves them to file after every press of button.

Everything works fine when I press the button using the mouse (its `button1_Click`). When I click the button, and then use it again by pressing enter key - the program crashes.

So there is the question: how can I prevent user for using my button using enter key? Or how can I "click button" while pressing enter without crash?

Answer (score -1):

Try to cancel the KeyDown Event for the Enter Key... 
Here is how do you do that: [QTextEdit - How to "cancel" entered key codes in onKeyPress()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591912/qtextedit-how-to-cancel-entered-key-codes-in-onkeypress)
Let me know it it worked.

Comment: During debugging button1_Click i got results:
EventArgs^  e has System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::LeftClick when i click it, but it is empty when I use enter. I don't know how to check this.